# Could not find process name ‘TaskExampleProcess’

Tags: javascript, node.js, bpmn

I clone this repository **https://github.com/e2ebridge/bpmn** into my local.
Then I attempt to follow its README.md to get start.
When I try building a REST server,I find it I **Could not find process name 'TaskExampleProcess'**

My developemnt enviroment:

```
Windows 10
npm v3.3.12
node v5.1.0
```

Problem Reproduction as follows:

---

server.js:

```
/**
 * Copyright: E2E Technologies Ltd
 */
"use strict";

var bpmn = require('../lib/public.js');
var path = require('path');

var port = 9998;
var urlMap = {
    "TaskExampleProcess": path.join(__dirname, "./resources/projects/simple/taskExampleProcess.bpmn")
};

// Returns a restify server.
var server = bpmn.createServer({urlMap: urlMap, logLevel: "debug"});

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

client.js:

```
var restify = require("restify");
  // This example used the node-restify client
  var client = restify.createJsonClient({url: "http://localhost:9998"});
  client.post('/TaskExampleProcess', function (err, req, res, obj) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

Step1: I run server.js, it has no errors, console output as follows:

```
BPMNProcessServer listening at http://[::]:9998
```

Step2: Then I run client.js, console output as follows:

```
{ [InvalidArgumentError: Could not find process name 'TaskExampleProcess'.]
  message: 'Could not find process name \'TaskExampleProcess\'.',
  statusCode: 409,
  body: 
   { code: 'InvalidArgument',
     message: 'Could not find process name \'TaskExampleProcess\'.' },
  restCode: 'InvalidArgument',
  name: 'InvalidArgumentError' }
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?What is the reason? How to solve it?
I  look forward to your  reply.Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the respective TaskExampleProcess.bpmn and TaskExampleProcess.js files?

Comment: I have taskExampleProcess.bpmn and taskExampleProcess.js.The first letter of file name I doesn't make uppercase.

Comment: I change file name "taskExampleProcess.bpmn" and "taskExampleProcess.js" to"TaskExampleProcess.bpmn" and "TaskExampleProcess.js" respectively.But it still doesn't solve this problem.